# How to change step value inside the loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

I want to increase my step value in each loop iteration, but my solution is not working.

```
n=1
(0..100).step(n) do |x|
 puts x
 n+=1 
end
```

Is there any way to change "n" or I'm must using "while loop" or smth else?

Comment: I doubt this would be doable. Even if it was, I don't think you *should*, because it breaks the generally-accepted behavior of `step`. Use explicit code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assuming you are trying to print 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21 etc.

[step documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-step) says:

> Iterates over range, passing each nth element to the block. If the range
>   contains numbers, n is added for each iteration.

So what you are trying to do can't be done with `step`. A `while` or traditional `for` loop should do the trick.

Comment: Can't be done with `Range#step`, but can indeed be done with `Numeric#step`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a custom [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerator.html) based on [Aurélien Bottazini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589323/477037):

```
tri = Enumerator.new do |y|
  n = 0
  step = 1
  loop do
    y << n
    n = n + step
    step += 1
  end
end

tri.take(10)
#=> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]

tri.take_while { |i| i < 100 }
#=> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91]
```

Comment: I don't mind the infinite loop here, it is in Enumerator, and is controlled clearly.  There is no hidden 'break' condition.  You control Enumerator appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do what you want is to use a while loop.

```
step = 1
last = 100
i = 0
while (i < last )
    puts i
    step += 1
    i += step
end
```

It might be possible to do it with step, but it requires you to fully understand how it works, and maybe using some hacky stuff to make it work. But why to do that when you have a simple solution already available to you?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with `loop` and a `break`

```
n = 0
step = 1
loop do
  puts n
  n = n + step
  step += 1
  break if n > 100
end
```

Comment: This can be nicely wrapped in a custom `Enumerator`.

Comment: Why use `break` and an infinite `loop` when you have a nice conditional statement that you can use with a `while` or `until` statement?

Comment: I first started with a ~begin while~ and rubocop suggested to use ~loop~. I found it interesting.

Comment: @vgoff within an enumerator `loop` makes perfect sense. I've posted a [separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26635201/477037) (too much for a comment).

Comment: Yes, loop does, you use it without a break.  @Stefan, I was referring to the `break` which I avoid, because `until n > 100` is up front, and clear, rather than having a `break` somewhere else in the code.  See my other comment under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are asking, now that I look at it again, is changing the argument given to `step` inside the block given to the `step` method.  This is not possible, due to the argument for step being evaluated before step can continue on its job of running the given block, and assigning the block variable `x`.

Comment: can you adjust `by:` in this example like in the question?

Comment: Incrementally, as in + 1, + 2, + 3, no, not dynamically.  No, not incrementally while running.  A while or until loop would be better at this, now that I look again.

Comment: I mistook his questions wording when he said "in each loop iteration" to mean inside the loops iteration, not outside being redefined.  But I think he meant the latter.  But this is not possible due to the scope of the `n` variable being to different things, to start with.